# How is a link to a Meeting Workspace stored for a Calendar Event?

Tags: calendar, object-model, meeting-workspace

If you open the DispForm.aspx for an item in a Calendar List, you see a link and display text to the Meeting Workspace (if one exists) for that event.

How can I access the link to the Meeting Workspace from the Object Model? There appears to be a boolean field called "Workspace" which says if one exists or not, but I can't seem to find a way to see which Workspace it links to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://siteurl"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList calendar = web.Lists["Calendar"];

                foreach (SPListItem item in calendar.Items)
                {
                    bool hasWorkspace = Convert.ToBoolean(item["WorkspaceLink"]);
                    if (hasWorkspace)
                    {
                        string workspace = item["Workspace"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Apologies, took too long to reply! That does work now, thanks. Not sure where I was going wrong, think I was (somehow) confusing Workspace and WorkspaceLink fields.

Thanks again.